# Sending password to rdesktop securely

Tags: linux, security, remote-desktop, password, rdesktop

I want to send password to rdesktop so that it doesn't show up in ps. Is there any safe alternative for passing with command-line parameter? I even can develop an application for this if it helps. Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a text file (named `secretfile` here) which contains your password. Then, you can connect using the following command:

```
$ cat secretfile | rdesktop -p - server_ip
```

This way the password will not show up in output of `ps`. Don't forget to change file permission to prevent other users from reading it!

Comment: well other processes of my user can read though. can I do it programmatically?